# How to use retrofit post params&body but i cant use @Filed(FormUrlEncoded)&@Body together . what can i do?

Tags: android, retrofit2

@FormUrlEncoded

@POST("/api/pofPortfolio/placeOrder/")Observable> placeOrder (@Field("type") String type,@Body RequestBody body);

  1.

Answer (score 0):

Run these code can get response，but I feel not quite right， anyone who got it?

@POST("/api/pofPortfolio/placeOrder/")Observable> placeOrder (@Query("type") String type,@Body RequestBody body);